# Julia: How to pivot a vector of vectors into vector of tuples, similar to zipping its elements

Tags: vector, julia, list-comprehension

I have a vector containing an unknown number of vectors, which all have the same length. For example, like this:

```
julia> a
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 5]
 [2, 6]
 [3, 7]
 [4, 8]
```

And I want to pivot it into a vector of tuples, exactly the way you would with `zip()`, like this:

```
julia> collect(zip(a...))
2-element Vector{NTuple{4, Int64}}:
 (1, 2, 3, 4)
 (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

However, I want to do this without using the *splat* (`...`) in there, since the splat will end up happening at compile-time if I understand correctly. I want something like `reduce(zip, a)`, but that's obviously not right:

```
julia> collect(reduce(zip, a))
2-element Vector{Tuple{Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Int64}, Int64}}:
 (((1, 2), 3), 4)
 (((5, 6), 7), 8)
```

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Am I correct that this use of splat is not performant?
2. What is the right way to do this operation performantly?

Thank you!

---

For reference, here is a performance characterization of the current approach. It actually appears surprisingly performant (though maybe it would be worse in-situ?):

```
julia> a = Any[collect(1:1_000_000), [2.0 for _ in 1:1_000_000]]
2-element Vector{Any}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  …  999991, 999992, 999993, 999994, 999995, 999996, 999997, 999998, 999999, 1000000]
 [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0  …  2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]

julia> @time collect(zip(a...))
  0.003288 seconds (4 allocations: 15.259 MiB)
1000000-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Float64}}:
 (1, 2.0)
 (2, 2.0)
 (3, 2.0)
 (4, 2.0)
 (5, 2.0)
 (6, 2.0)
 ⋮
 (999996, 2.0)
 (999997, 2.0)
 (999998, 2.0)
 (999999, 2.0)
 (1000000, 2.0)
```

Comment: my bet is that if your vectors are as long as the last example the splat operator is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `invert` function from SplitApplyCombine.jl

```
julia> invert(a)
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
 [5, 6, 7, 8]

julia> Tuple.(invert(a))
2-element Vector{NTuple{4, Int64}}:
 (1, 2, 3, 4)
 (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The second version broadcasts `Tuple` over the result to get a vector of tuples instead of a vector of vectors. The first version is the faster among the two, but both versions are faster than the `collect(zip(...))` method in my benchmarks.